# JAVA 1.7 and Mysql 5.7 connection

Tags: java, mysql

I have Java jdk1.7xxx installed and a MySQL database v5.7 too.
My database is named "mydb".
I access it from the mysql console.

However when I try to access it from my java program it makes an error "source of data unknown, or pilot name not specified". So I am missing some pilot/extra file I guess. But I did import java.sql.* at the beginning of my program..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


 public class DPIA_impacts extends JFrame {
    // Labels 
    JLabel lb_title;
    JTable tableau = null;
    static JPanel p_global, p_title, p_center, p_south;
    JScrollPane scroll=null;
    JButton btn_Save, btn_Export;
    //DefaultTableModel model;
 ArrayList t1=new ArrayList();
 ArrayList t2=new ArrayList();
 ArrayList t3=new ArrayList();


 public DPIA_impacts(){
  //declarations
    p_global = new JPanel();
    p_title = new JPanel();
    p_center = new JPanel();
    p_south = new JPanel();
    lb_title = new JLabel("DPIA meeting: fill the table !");
    btn_Save = new JButton("Save");
    btn_Export = new JButton("Export");
    scroll = new JScrollPane();
  // add tool tip text to the Save and Export buttons
    btn_Save.setToolTipText("Save to the database Impacts table");
    btn_Export.setToolTipText("Exports the contents of the Jtable to an Excel file");
  // add Action Listener to the buttons
    btn_Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             //Execute when button is pressed
             System.out.println("You clicked the button SAVE");
             String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
             String login = "root";
             String passwd = "toor";
             Connection cn = null;
             Statement st = null;

             try {
                //chargement du driver 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                // Recup connexion
                cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, passwd);
                // Creation d'un statement
                st = cn.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM impacts";
                st.executeUpdate(sql);

                //instruction.executeQuery(req);
            } // Try
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Connexion à la base de données impossible");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Pilote de connexion introuvable");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            //}//end catch
            } finally {
                try{
                    cn.close();
                    st.close();
                } catch (SQLException sqle){
                    sqle.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }}); 
    btn_Export.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             //Execute when button is pressed
             System.out.println("You clicked the button EXPORT");
         }
     }); 
  //add the components to the righ panels
    p_title.add(lb_title);
    p_center.add(scroll);     
    p_south.add(btn_Save, BorderLayout.WEST);
    p_south.add(btn_Export, BorderLayout.EAST); 

    String req = "SELECT * FROM impacts"; 
    int i =0;

    Connect resultat = new Connect(req,1,"BaseDeDonnees"); 

    // connexion a la base de donnees
 }//end constructor

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Create and set up the window.
    DPIA_impacts f = new DPIA_impacts();
    f.setTitle("DPIA: check the impacts");
    //f = new JFrame("DPIA: Impacts");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Set up the content pane

 f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 f.getContentPane().add(p_title, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
 f.getContentPane().add(p_center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 f.getContentPane().add(p_south, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
 f.pack();
 f.setSize(500, 300);
 f.setVisible(true);
 }//end main

 }//end programm !
```

[image: screenshot Error]

Adding the jar:

[image: add the jar doesn't solve the issue]

Comment: Would you please add your full error log ? @tom

Comment: @SkyWalker: done, screenshot added

Comment: Don't use screenshots, when text will do (and you can copy the text from the commandline).

Comment: The error suggests you are executing code that uses an url that starts with `jdbc:odbc:`, not with `jdbc:mysql:`. BTW: You really should not be compiling code in `C:\Program Files`, if you are not running cmd as administrator, the created class file might not end up where you expect and you might still be running the old class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";`
you forgot to write the port number.
try `String url ="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb";`

**UPDATE**

Ok, just try this code and run it from Eclipse and not from cmd.
Also you use `executeUpdate` for `INSERT`. For `SELECT` you use `executeQuery`.

```
  //Execute when button is pressed
            System.out.println("You clicked the button SAVE");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb";
            String login = "root";
            String passwd = "toor";
            Connection cn = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            System.out.println("Connecting to database..");
            try {

                cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, passwd);
                System.out.println("Database Connected");
               st = cn.createStatement();
               String sql = "SELECT * FROM impacts";
               rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
               while (rs.next()){
                   //do something
               }


               //instruction.executeQuery(req);
           } // Try
           catch (SQLException ex)
           {
               System.out.println("Connexion à la base de données impossible");
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
            finally {
               try{
                   if (cn != null ){
                       cn.close();
                       }               
                       if (st != null ){
                           st.close();
                           }  
                       if (rs != null ){
                           rs.close();
                           }  
               } catch (SQLException sqle){
                   sqle.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
```

Comment: Hello Ioanna, no unfortunately, I got exactly the same error as before

Comment: Did you add the mysql jdbc driver jar to your classpath?

Comment: hello Ioanna, I tried to add the jar, see the screenshot, not working. Maybe I don't do it correctly...

Comment: Maybe it is something has to do with permissions. I would recommend 
1.to move all your files to C:\
2.to run cmd as an administrator
3.go to control panel -> user account control settings (or write uac to search) and change to never notify
then try to copy paste by hand the .jar file to your project

Comment: Hi, I added the jar to Eclipse. However I still cannot connect to my database

Comment: In Eclispse I added the com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar and the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Comment: The jar you need to add in Eclipse is the mysql-connector-java-X.X.X-bin.jar

Comment: Thanks, executeQuery worked (OK not really worked because I don't retrieve yet my results, but at least I have no longer the connection error). :-)